# Quais são os métodos de requisição HTTP, e qual é a diferença entre eles?

Tags: http, http-métodos

Quais são os métodos de requisição HTTP, entre os quais estão `GET`, `POST` e `DELETE`? Para que se deve usar cada um deles, e qual é a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

- **GET**: Requisita um representação do recurso especificado (O mesmo recurso pode ter várias representações, ao exemplo de serviços que retornam XML e JSON).
- **HEAD**: Retorna os cabeçalhos de uma resposta (sem o corpo contendo o recurso)
- **POST**: Envia uma entidade e requisita que o servidor aceita-a como subordinada do recurso identificado pela URI.
- **PUT**: Requisita que um entidade seja armazenada embaixo da URI fornecida. Se a URI se refere a um recurso que já existe, ele é modificado; se a URI não aponta para um recurso existente, então o servidor pode criar o recurso com essa URI.
- **DELETE**: Apaga o recurso especificado.
- **TRACE**: Ecoa de volta a requisição recebida para que o cliente veja se houveram mudanças e adições feitas por servidores intermediários.
- **OPTIONS**: Retorna os métodos HTTP que o servidor suporta para a URL especificada.
- **CONNECT**: Converte a requisição de conexão para um túnel TCP/IP transparente, usualmente para facilitar comunicação criptografada com SSL (HTTPS) através de um proxy HTTP não criptografado.
- **PATCH**: Usado para aplicar modificações parciais a um recurso.

---

Fonte: [Wikipedia - Hypertext Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)

Comment: Nossa, o HEAD já era novidade pra mim. A maioria dos programadores nem se preocupam com esses outros métodos, não é mesmo? Será que seria válido pedir exemplos de usos desses outros métodos, pelo menos uma descrição?

Comment: Os dois últimos são métodos mais obscuros. O `trace` também não é tão utilizado assim (mais para diagnosticar problemas no meio do caminho). `GET` e `POST` são triviais, e os demais são empregados em APIs [REST](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST).

Comment: Sobre pedir exemplos, eu acho que é válido dentro de um contexto mais específico (Como "quando devo usar `POST` vs `PUT`?"), a comunidade tende a não gostar muito de perguntas amplas (vide o voto para que essa pergunta fosse fechada).

Comment: Existem ainda as extensões de método, que podem usar `-` e apesar de não serem "oficiais" depende só do servidor ter a interpretação do método, por exemplo `MEU-METODO` faz o que eu quiser no lado do servidor.

Comment: Um exemplo de extensão são os métodos do [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV).

Comment: Diz no wiki que é um protocolo... é também um método de requisição HTTP?

Comment: É um protocolo que estende o HTTP com mais alguns métodos que só fazem sentido para o próprio protocolo (expondo uma espécie de repositório de arquivos através de HTTP).

Answer (score 6):

Basicamente, se foi isso que eu entendi, existem 8 tipos de métodos dos quais:

GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, CONNECT, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS.

**GET**: Método que solicita algum recurso ou objeto ao servidor

**HEAD**: Solicita informações de um determinado objeto sem que esse seja enviado ao cliente apenas para testar a validade do último acesso.

**POST**: Método usado para envio de arquivo/dados ou formulário HTML ao servidor.

**OPTIONS**: Por meio desse método o cliente obtém as propriedades do servidor.

**DELETE**: Informa por meio do URL o objeto a ser deletado.

**TRACE**: Para enviar mensagem do tipo loopback para teste.

**PUT**: Aceita criar ou modificar algum objeto do servidor.

**CONNECT**: Comunicar com servidores Proxy.

Fontes: http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Um-pouco-do-protocolo-HTTP?pagina=4

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Answer (score 1):

`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` são muito utilizado em projectos de web `API` e representam as operações `CRUD` utilizadas habitualmente em bases de dados.