# Como posso verificar se existe um arquivo em uma URL com IdHttp?

Tags: delphi, http-request

Preciso verificar se um determinado arquivo *online* é existente, se for retornar *True*, se não, *False*. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Te aconselharia a trocar o Indy pelo IPWorks, se você tiver condições, é claro. Eu usei Indy por muito tempo, mas tinha muito bug e por fim acabei trocando, não estou me lembrando como fazia isso que você quer. Se você vier a trocar me avise, pois daí saberei a resposta.

Comment: Aonde encontro esse componente IPWorks amigo ?

Comment: Esse que é o problema, ele é pago, mas você pode baixar a versão de trial aqui: http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ Mas se eu não me engano ele já vem instalado com alguma das versões mais novas do Delphi, tipo o XE2, XE3, seila. Procure por `IP*Workws!` no seu Tool Palette, talvez você já até tem ele e não sabe. Qual sua versão de Delphi?

Comment: OK vou testar, obrigado amigo..

Answer (score 3):

Isso pode ser feito através de uma requisição HTTP com o método [`HEAD`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HEAD) para solicitar informações de um determinado recurso, sem que o mesmo seja retornado.

Segundo a [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HEAD):

> Variação do GET em que o recurso não é retornado. É usado para obter metainformações por meio do cabeçalho da resposta, sem ter que recuperar todo o conteúdo.

Relacionado: [**Quais são os métodos de requisição HTTP, e qual é a diferença entre eles?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9419/6454)

Veja um exemplo:

```pascal
// Uses: IdHTTP, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient; 

function CheckFileOnlineExists(const OnlineFile: string; var Size: Int64): Boolean;
var
 IdHttp: TIdHTTP;
begin
try
  IdHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHttp.Head(OnlineFile);
    Size := IdHttp.Response.ContentLength;
    if Size > 0 then
      Result := True
    else
      Result := False;
  except on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
    // Fazer algo aqui caso você queira tratar alguma exceção do IdHttp
  end;
  end;
finally
  IdHttp.Free;
end;
end;
```

O primeiro parâmetro da função `CheckFileOnlineExists` é o link do arquivo a ser verificado, e o segundo parâmetro é uma variável do tipo *inteiro* que vai receber o *content-length* da requisição (embora não tenha sido pedido na questão).

Exemplo de uso:

```pascal
Const
 LINK = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/br/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=3958fdf06794';
Var
 FileStatus: Boolean;
 FileSize: Int64;
begin
 FileStatus := CheckFileOnlineExists(LINK, FileSize);

 if FileStatus then
   ShowMessage(Format('Arquivo existente! Tamanho em bytes %d.', [FileSize]))
 else
   ShowMessage('Esse arquivo não existe!');
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica,funcionou perfeitamente!