# Qual é a diferença entre o método PUT e o POST?

Tags: http, http-métodos

Alguns ensinam que `POST` é para enviar dados para criação de algo e que `PUT` é para atualizar, mas achei mal explicado.

Então, afinal, qual é a diferença entre o método PUT e o POST?

Quando devo usar um e outro?

Comment: Acho que é mais conceitual, mas sempre quis saber isso também.

Comment: Quando alguém comentou sobre essas definições, falaram algo sobre rest?

Comment: A diferença entre os dois é explicada no seguinte link: [Method Definitions - PUT](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) (estou com preguiça de traduzir o 3º paragrafo da desta seção).

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (que não responde a dúvida): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322

Comment: Tô esperando alguém colocar uma resposta com aquela palavra bonita ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Tecnicamente nenhuma. Apenas a semântica muda. [Leia a RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5):

> A diferença fundamental entre requisições POST e PUT é refletida na diferença de significado da Request-URI. O URI em uma requisição POST identifica o recurso que manipulará a entidade anexa. O recursos pode ser um processo de aceitação de dados, um *gateway* para outro protocolo, ou uma entidade separada que aceita anotações. Em contraste, o URI na requisição PUT identifica a entidade anexa com a requisição -- o *user agent*  sabe qual URI é intencionado e o servidor NÃO DEVE tentar aplicar a requisição para outro recurso. Se o servidor deseja que a requisição seja aplicada para um URI diferente, ele DEVE enviar uma resposta 301 (Moved Permanently); o *user agent* PODE então tomar sua própria decisão sobre redirecionar ou não a requisição.

Ou seja, o PUT deveria ser usado em situações mais específicas onde se quer enviar uma informação e não fazer mais nada além de armazená-la de alguma forma. O POST é mais geral, pressupõe que a informação é apenas parte do processo que será realizado. O POST permite ter efeitos colaterais quaisquer, ou pelo menos é esperado que isto possa ocorrer. Espera-se que o PUT não tenha algo desconhecido, ou indesejável. Ele é [idempotente](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.2) (homenagem ao bfavaretto).

Em alguns cenários é possível pensar em semânticas mais específicas (REST, estou falando de você) para cada verbo. Mas essencialmente eles funcionam de forma análoga. Em cenários de CRUD, o PUT **normalmente** é usado para atualizar algo e o POST para criar (ou fazer outras operações que não se encaixa no CRUD básico), assim como o GET é usado para ler, e o DELETE obviamente para apagar.

Claro que a recomendação é seguir o que diz a RFC, mas é quase seguro dizer que não importa muito. No futuro poderia ser que impusessem alguma restrição ou ter algum efeito baseado no que diz a RFC. E aí tudo o que não seguisse ela, teria problemas. "Legalmente" poderiam fazer isto, mas como ninguém segue a RFC, quebraria tanta coisa, que isto nunca vai ser mudado.

Na dúvida, todos usam o `POST` que é mais conhecido e deve funcionar sempre. Tenho minhas dúvidas se não deveria ser o contrário. Mas o estrago já está feito.

Embora não responda diretamente, aconselho fortemente ler a [resposta indicada pelo bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322). Tem [outra útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9419/101) também.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 17):

O `post` é um verbo `HTTP` para submissão de dados dentro do pacote em qualquer tipo de requisição, muito similar ao `get`, mudando apenas o local e tamanho disponível para armazenamento dos dados. Em contra partida o `put` é um verbo que carrega o significado de criar elementos, como o envio de um arquivo ou entidade.

## Update 1

Ao solicitar um recurso, como uma consulta, é usual utilizarmos a passagem de informação usando `get`.

```
URI: http://servidor/recurso/consulta/{id}
GET: {id}
```

Entretanto, utilizar o verbo `get` gera `URI's` individuais para cada valor informado, expondo a informação e impossibilitando uma otimização de cache caso a resposta da requisição seja a mesma. Desta maneira temos o verbo `post` para carregar as informações dentro do pacote sem constar na `URI`.

```
URI: http://servidor/recurso/consulta
POST: {id}
```

Os verbos `put` e `delete` são carregados de semântica. Ao se criar ou transferir um recurso o verbo mais adequado é o `put`. Para excluir um recurso o verbo mais adequado é o `delete`.

```
URI: http://servidor/recurso/novo
PUT: {nome,cidade,estado}

URI: http://servidor/recurso/excluir/{id}
DELETE
```

Comment: Gente, se ele está errado na resposta, eu gostaria de saber o por quê pelo menos! Sou leigo nesse assunto!

Comment: +1 pois não achei que -1 seria justo. Pelo que vi respondeu rápido e com as próprias palavras, e o contexto soa com algumas respostas por ai que já vi que são cópias de posts pela net.

Comment: Esse pessoal dos negativos estão queimando o filme da comunidade! O pessoal sabe negativar, mas não sabe dar feedbacks.

Comment: +1 pois não é uma resposta de todo mal, no entanto nas **proximas** respostas recomendo fornecer detalhes OU uma fonte, isso **ajuda** a sua resposta ter uma *qualidade maior*, não que ela não tenha.

Comment: Boa noite @MFedatto a sua resposta esta sendo discutida aqui se quiser participar seja bem vindo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4446/3635 O **meta** é um lugar legal pra discutirmos e tentarmos resolver, portanto não leve a mal se algo entoar alguma coisa que não gostar :)

Comment: Opa, @GuilhermeNascimento! Eu desativei as notificações por email porque estou sempre passando por aqui durante a semana. Eu entendo perfeitamente não receber +1 de quem achar que a resposta pdoeria ser mais completa, mas acredito que minha resposta está correta e responde a pergunta inicial, então não vejo motivo pra -1. De qualquer forma, vou colocar alguns exemplos.

Comment: @MFedatto isto esta sendo discutido no meta, sinta-se a vontade pra falar disto lá. Acho que a minha resposta deve deixar bem claro como evitar os tais votos, independente deles parecerem certos ou não.

Comment: A resposta não é de toda ruim, o problema está mais na aplicação "verbal", definir o significado de uma requisição ao significado gramatical "verbo" é uma má definição do comportamento da mesma. Embora as "palavras" put, get e delete sejam verbos de ação, seu comportamento não se tratam de um verbo e sim de requisições. Porém não o negativarei por um detalhe simples desse.

Comment: @IvanFerrer verbo é o termo técnico adequado. `POST`, `GET`, `PUT` e `DELETE` são verbos `HTTP`.

Comment: Concordo que são "verbos" HTTP, que é justamente o diferencial entre o significado de "parâmetros" porém, eu particularmente, não gosto de ver alguém usando emprego de verbo como termo técnico. Eu manteria isso no português, que é onde "verbo" tem mais sentido e significado, mesmo que tenhamos que usar verbos para representar as chamadas.

Comment: Parece que alguém assassinou a linguagem gramatical e se apropriou de seu uso para embromar termologia técnica sem sentido, provavelmente o que danificou o sentido, foi a tradução para o português de "verbose" e a atribuição para a propriedade dando outro sentido e significado. Mas enfim, é só uma opinião. Por isso não negativei.

Comment: É a tradução para "verb". Verbose se traduz verbosidade. Na literatura específica você encontra `http verbs` e `verbos http`.

Answer (score 14):

**PUT** coloca um arquivo ou recurso em um `URI` específico. Se já existe um arquivo ou recurso nesse `URI`, o método `PUT` irá substituir o arquivo (ou recurso). Se não houver nenhum arquivo ou recurso lá, o método `PUT` cria um.

**POST** envia dados para um `URI` específico para manipular a solicitação. O servidor `web`, neste ponto pode determinar o que fazer com os dados no contexto do recurso especificado.

[fonte (inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107390/whats-the-difference-between-a-post-and-a-put-http-request)

Comment: uma revisão no texto seria bacana.. complicado entender pois parece que apenas traduziu com google translate e jogou aqui. Aliás, só para confirmar, copiei os originais e joguei no translate... Deu exatemente igual ... com os mesmos erros gramaticais.

Comment: @DanielOmine foi exatamente isso! Copiei o texto e quando ia alterar apareceu uma tarefa urgente aqui, e tive que deixar pra outra hora, rs.

Answer (score 1):

**PUT** é uma operação idempotente para "colocar" (CRIAR OU SUBSTITUIR) um recurso em uma determinada URL, em outras palavras, é usado quando a URL identifica unicamente o recurso a ser criado ou atualizado, e se a operação for bem sucedida vai haver após um recurso naquela URL exatamente como você enviou, independente do que havia antes.

Para os demais casos, use **POST**.

Por exemplo, vamos supor uma api que permite criar ou atualizar usuários:
**POST /user** retorna um novo usuário com os metadados enviados no corpo da requisição. Normalmente o ID é criado no servidor e retornado na resposta.
**PUT /user/12345** cria ou substitui o usuário 12345 com as informações enviadas no corpo da requisição

Note que no primeiro caso se repetirmos a mesma requisição teoricamente vamos estar criando outro usuário com os mesmos dados (mas com ids diferentes), ou a segunda requisição retornará algum erro, já no segundo caso vamos estar substituindo o usuário 12345 por outro exatamente igual se os dados no corpo da requisição forem os mesmos.

Obs: PUT é usado quando enviamos um objeto completo. Se você quiser atualizar só uma parte dele e não reenviar tudo, use PATCH.