# Duvida $http AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um form onde alguns inputs que serão utilizados para fazer um filtro, so que como são muitos, para não precisar passar os campos via GET desta forma:
Ex: ?filtro1=teste&filtro2=teste2 ..., posso utilizar o metodo $http.post do angularjs sem nenhum problema ?
É errado utilizar dessa forma ?

Comment: São abordagens diferentes. Dá pra fazer, dá! Porém a decisão entre utilizar um GET ou um POST vai além da decisão de apenas funcionar!

Comment: Exato Murilo, por isso minha duvida, se é uma abordagem correta, funcionar esta funcionando perfeitamente mas não sei se é correto.

Comment: Não há erro nenhum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há problema nenhum em utilizar o método POST, ao invés de GET. Este método é mais seguro e tem uma capacidade de dados melhor que o GET. Nesse método uma conexão paralela é aberta e os dados são passados por ela. Não há restrição referente ao tamanho (Porém esse tamanho pode ser limitado se desejar, basta fazer essa pequena configuração no servidor:  `php_value post_max_size 20M`), além disso os dados não são visíveis ao usuário.

Já o método GET, é recomendado quando se deseja passar poucas/pequenas informações para realizar uma pesquisa ou simplesmente passar uma informação para outra página através da URL (barra de endereços).

O que não pode acontecer é as suas requisições resultarem em mudanças no conteúdo da resposta. A função do método GET é pura e simplesmente recuperar um recurso existente no servidor, se você usa para alterar dados, você estará fazendo mal uso e abrindo brechas de segurança.

O resultado de uma requisição GET é “cacheável” pelo cliente, ou seja, fica no histórico do navegador.

Dá uma lida nesta [**pergunta do SOpt**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92870/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-m%C3%A9todo-put-e-o-post), que tem mais detalhes interessantes para você saber.

Answer (score 0):

Guilherme, conforme citado pelo @MuriloMittmann, é possível fazer sim, mas não foi feito para isso, o ideal é utilizar `GET`.

O protocolo http descreve que `GET` deve ser utilizado para solicitar recursos, de maneira que esta solicitação não altere o estado do servidor, portanto vários requests em sequência podem ocorrer sem gerar problemas.

Com relação ao `POST`, o protocolo descreve que ele é para submissão de formulários ou envio de informações para processamento que possivelmente levarão a uma alteração no estado do servidor.

Sendo assim, filosoficamente o correto seria utilizar-se de `GET`.

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo.

Comment: Então na verdade essa decisão fica a critério do programador.

Comment: Exato. os verbos do http tem sua definição, mas fora do "estado da arte", é liberado o uso de acordo com o gosto.