# Qual o verbo HTTP que eu uso para logout?

Tags: api, http

Tenho um endpoint de logout para tornar inválido o token do usuário current.

Com isso me surgiu uma dúvida: Qual verbo HTTP devo utilizar para realizar logout?

Comment: Você quer dizer semanticamente?

Comment: @LINQ Isso mesmo.

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322/5878)

Comment: *usuário curren* seria alguma mistura de português com o inglês? Poderia ser traduzido por usuário atual?

Comment: como você invalida o token do usuário? se está querendo fazer um servidor RESTful esse endpoint não faz sentido

Comment: @J.Guilherme eu estou utilizando JWT e nessa lib tem uma função para deixar o token inválido. Claro que faz sentido cara, imagine a seguinte situação o cara faz logout na aplicação e vc apenas remove a SESSION da aplicação. Então se de alguma forma(nunca confie no usuário) o cara pegar o token do último usuário logado, ele vai conseguir fazer qualquer request. Se você pesquisar um pouco vai entender a real necessidade.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49322/quais-as-vantagens-de-se-utilizar-os-m%c3%a9todos-http-corretos)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basta analisar as recomendações definidas nas [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), seção 9, *Method Definitions*.

> **DELETE**
>
> The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI. This method MAY be overridden by human intervention (or other means) on the origin server. The client cannot be guaranteed that the operation has been carried out, even if the status code returned from the origin server indicates that the action has been completed successfully. However, the server SHOULD NOT indicate success unless, at the time the response is given, it intends to delete the resource or move it to an inaccessible location.
>
> A successful response SHOULD be 200 (OK) if the response includes an entity describing the status, 202 (Accepted) if the action has not yet been enacted, or 204 (No Content) if the action has been enacted but the response does not include an entity.
>
> If the request passes through a cache and the Request-URI identifies one or more currently cached entities, those entries SHOULD be treated as stale. Responses to this method are not cacheable.

Considerando que o acesso à aplicação é um recurso identificado pelo *token* e que você deseja excluir este *token*, descontinuando o acesso, então o método DELETE é o apropriado.

**Tradução livre:**

O método DELETE solicita que o servidor de origem exclua o recurso identificado pela *Request-URI*. Este método pode ser substituído por uma intervenção humana (ou outros meios) no servidor de origem. O cliente não pode garantir que a operação tenha sido realizada, mesmo que o código de status retornado do servidor de origem indique que a ação foi concluída com sucesso. No entanto, o servidor NÃO DEVE indicar sucesso a menos que, no momento em que a resposta for dada, pretende excluir o recurso ou movê-lo para um local inacessível.

Uma resposta bem sucedida DEVE ser 200 (OK) se a resposta incluir uma entidade que descreva o status, 202 (Aceito) se a ação ainda não foi promulgada ou 204 (Sem Conteúdo) se a ação foi promulgada, mas a resposta não inclui uma entidade.

Se a solicitação passar por um cache e o URI de solicitação identifica uma ou mais entidades atualmente armazenadas em cache, essas entradas DEVEM ser tratadas como obsoletas. As respostas a este método não são armazenáveis em cache.

---

**Nota pessoal:**

Se você possui domínio completo sobre o desenvolvimento da API, isto é, você desenvolveu tanto a API quando o cliente, você poderá confiar na resposta 200, fugindo levemente da recomendação acima, pois na API você poderá retornar a resposta 200 **apenas** quando o recurso for devidamente excluído. A recomendação define que a resposta não deve ser confiável principalmente quando você está utilizando uma API de terceiros.

---

**Leituras recomendadas**

[Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322/5878)

[Qual é a diferença entre o método PUT e o POST?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92870/5878)

Comment: Obrigado por tirar minha dúvida.

Answer (score 6):

Eu diria que um método interessante para o uso seria o `DELETE` (com base em uma API que conheço da IBM), pois quando você faz a autenticação você cria um Token de acesso e quando você vai desconectar este Token não pode ser mais usado, então creio que `DELETE` descreve bem:

```
DELETE /api/1.0/token HTTP/1.1
```

A resposta de `status` pode variar um pouco dependendo se o Token existe ou não, conforme o https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7 o status de resposta deve ser:

- `200 (Ok)` se retornar uma descrição no corpo
- `201 (Accepted)` se a ação ainda não tiver sido concluída (provavelmente se for checar posteriormente)
- `204 (No Content)` se a ação não tiver uma resposta no corpo

> **Nota:** Se a solicitação passar por um cache e a URL da solicitação identifica uma ou mais entidades armazenadas em cache, essas entradas *DEVEM* ser tratadas como **obsoletas**. As respostas a este método não devem ser armazenadas em cache.