# Qual a diferença entre os metodos Get, Push, Post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-request

Queria saber a diferença entre os 3 no Javascript, tinham me dito que ambos fazem a mesma coisa mas tem semânticas diferentes. Mas não explicaram o que.

Comment: Métodos? Você está falando de verbos HTTP?

Comment: Também acredito que seja isso LINQ e que está acontecendo uma pequena confusão em relação ao push que não tem nada de parecido com o get e o post.

Comment: creio que esteja falando de get path e put

Comment: Creio que você está se referindo às requisições *HTTP*. Se for isso, esse post vai te ajudar: [Quais são os métodos de requisição HTTP e qual é a diferença entre eles?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9419/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-m%C3%A9todos-de-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-http-e-qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-eles)

Comment: Otimo, era isso msm, obg!