# O que o servidor deve retornar em uma requisição do tipo OPTIONS?

Tags: http, http-métodos

Antes de enviar qualquer requisição ao servidor, os navegadores automaticamente enviam, antes, uma requisição do tipo `OPTIONS` para saber algumas informações do servidor

Que informações o servidor precisam enviar? Apenas os cabeçalhos CORS?

Essas informações devem ser enviadas apenas nessas requisições ou nas demais também? (por questão de compatibilidade com navegadores antigos ou algo assim)

Essas requisições precisam passar por autenticação?

Achei [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9419/) onde diz apenas uma frase não muito específica do que deve ser retornado

Answer (score 7):

### OPTIONS

O Método `OPTIONS` é um método `HTTP`, que é utilizado para descobrir quais as opções de requisições permitidas para determinados recursos para um servidor, por isso essa requisição é feita antes das outras, para descobrir permissões que você aceita.

Nessa requisição, o servidor retorna uma lista de cabeçalhos, contendo alguns dados, mas também pode retornar um erro, caso não tenha nenhuma requisição para os recursos.

Esse envio pode ser feito de duas formas, a primeira é especificando uma `URL` na requisição, para uma análise específica:

```
OPTIONS /index.html HTTP/1.1
```

A outra forma é indicar com asterisco (*), que refere-se ao recursos como um todo:

```
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
```

Essa requisição é feita inicialmente para descobrir as permissões oferecidas para os recursos, para assim poder utilizar as outras requisições sem retornar erro.

Para uma simples requisição, é possível utilizar o `CURL`, para enviar essa requisição de confirmação, por exemplo:

```
curl -X OPTIONS http://index.html -i
```

Nessa requisição, por padrão, se existir campos permitidos, o servidor irá retornar um cabeçalho do tipo `Allow`, que indica quais métodos você aceita e tem permissão de requisição, mas retornando os dados somente como uma informação:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 11:45:00 GMT
Expires: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 11:45:00 GMT
Server: EOS (lax004/2813)
x-ec-custom-error: 1
Content-Length: 0
```

Caso não tiver requisições permitidas, o servidor irá retornar um cabeçalho vazio, que pode ocorrer temporariamente para algum recurso.

As informações do `OPTIONS`, são feitas somente nessa requisição, para informar quais métodos você aceita fazer. Não é utilizada para confirmação de envio.

### CORS

É uma especificação utilizada para definir trocas de recursos entre browser e servidor, de forma segura, não permitindo que scripts façam solicitações de origem cruzada.

Uma requisição, feita com `CORS`, é utilizada para saber se o servidor permite um tipo de requisição específica, informando os parâmetros para serem analisados, ou seja, é feita uma verificação de permissão "customizada" para o servidor.

> [Aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS), tem uma lista de cabeçalhos `CORS` que podem ser utilizados
>   em uma requisição.

Um exemplo, é criada uma requisição, para saber se uma requisição específica que utiliza `POST` e tem cabeçalhos customizados é aceita. Utiliza-se os cabeçalhos `Access-Control-Request-Method`, para o `POST` e o `Access-Control-Request-Headers`, para os cabeçalhos customizados:

```
OPTIONS /resources/post-here/ HTTP/1.1 
Host: bar.other 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate 
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 
Connection: keep-alive 
Origin: http://foo.example 
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST 
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
```

A partir dessa requisição "customizada", o servidor analisa e se permitir, retornará com os cabeçalhos, informando se os cabeçalhos dos campos específicos informados, podem ser solicitados. Essa resposta é parecida com uma resposta `Allow`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2008 01:15:39 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.0.61 (Unix) 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type 
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400 
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Origin 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Content-Length: 0 
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Content-Type: text/plain
```

O mecanismo `CORS`, suporta solicitações seguras de origem cruzada, que são as solicitações com origem (domínio, protocolo e porta) diferente da sua própria origem. Com isso, a requisição passam pela autenticação feita pelo servidor e retorna o resultado, para a partir disso solicitar uma requisição cruzada.

Em uma requisição com `CORS`, o navegador faz uma requisição, onde é passado cabeçalhos específicos, por exemplo, um cabeçalho `Access-Control-Request-Method`, que vai solicitar métodos que são permitidos e o servidor irá responder com `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, ou seja, o navegador solicita uma confirmação, o servidor responde com um cabeçalho, informando o que é permitido e com o retorno, o navegador verifica os dados retornados, se compatível, o navegador irá liberar a solicitação cruzada, entre domínios diferentes.

#### Compatibilidade

Todos os navegadores tem suporte básico a esse tipo de requisição, tanto navegadores mobile, quanto para desktop:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Mais Leitura

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS
- https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Me parece que sua resposta explica o que é o `OPTIONS` mas não explica exatamente o que deve ser retornado nesse tipo de requisição, pela sua resposta, entendi que nesse tipo de requisição só precisa retornar o cabeçalho `Allow`, nada mais, isso está correto?. Na prática qual a diferença entre `Allow` e `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`?

Comment: Essa pergunta _"Essas informações devem ser enviadas apenas nessas requisições ou nas demais também?"_ se refere a requisições do tipo `OPTIONS` e não ao CORS

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam fiz algumas alterações no texto

Comment: Nos links que passou está escrito _"Responses to the OPTIONS method are not cacheable"_, se a resposta não pode ser cacheada por que, no seu exemplo, tem cache?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam realmente, ele não é "cacheável". Só que esse tipo de requisição, traz o que é liberado e o que pode ser utilizado. O exemplo, veio do próprio site do MDN. É tanto que se você utilizar no cmd o `curl -X OPTIONS https://developer.mozilla.org -i`, apontando para o site deles, também retornará um cabeçalho com informações parecidas.